# Which hardware upgrade will give me the greatest performance boost with Ubuntu 11.10(with list of currently installed hardware)?

Tags: upgrade, hardware, performance

I have the following components in my computer:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArazBkOGrxEbdDhjc1lJWklJMEV5RlVrdzVYcHdMYWc

The system currently works okay with Ubuntu 11.10 and unity. It just seems a little clunky. Which hardware upgrade would give me greatest performance boost in Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: How much of that Kingston memory do you have? It's definitely going to make a difference.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot that. 4gb of ram. Updated the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add an SSD for your root partition , it could speed up your booting process at least.

[SSD on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive)

I don't know how much GPU can affect video performance ,  i never tried on my laptop.